# App Inventor Listpicker, Select specific text

Tags: textselection, app-inventor, listpicker

I need to get a specific section of text from the listpicker results. So far I can get the item I select to appear in an alert box. I need to set a specific part of that listpicker selection for mysql delete.

example: `24 - 1234567 - DTV - 25-02-2015`

I need to use the '24' as this is a row id from my sql db. I can then insert this into my blocks and add to php script to delete that row.

Block Code so far for listpicker:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgBhw.png

Comment: Unfortunately as new user at stackoverflow you are not allowed to insert a screenshot. Sorry, I do not like to click onto unknown webpages to take a look at it. You could upload it to imgur.com or post in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest) instead... PS: I don't know, why someone downvoted your post...

Comment: Amended web link.Thankyou for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to create 2 lists in your `Web.GotText` event: list `cpetypelistpicker` to display in the listpicker as you already have and a second list with only the rowids, let's call that list `listRowIds`.

In the `for each in list` loop of the `Web.GotText` event add additionally:

[image]

Then in the `Listpicker.AfterPicking` event just select the corresponding item from the second list using the `Listpicker.SelectionIndex` like this

[image]

Comment: Runtime Error
The operation select list item cannot accept the arguments: *empty-string* 1
This is empty as i set initialize global rowid to a blank text box

Comment: Did you forget to create the second list and **to add the rowids in the Web.GotText event**? Please edit your question and add an updated screenshot.

Comment: @ Taifun http://imgur.com/1fV708W  If i dont delete the items from the listpicker it works perfectly. If i delete an item It seems to have a strange anomally. The first item i select shows the correct rowid and will delete it fine.  However when i select another item from the list it seems to mess up the rowid! i then get the following message `Cannot parse text argument to "list from csv table" as a CSV-formatted table`

Comment: You have to keep you lists synchronized. If you delete an item from list1, you also have to delete the corresponding item in list2

Comment: How do you suggest i do that please? i do not understand what or how i need to do this.

Comment: please ask a new question and add a screenshot of your relevant blocks

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/671o6v8/new You suggested i have to keep my lists synchronized. When i delete the item from list one how do i ensure that list two is also deleted. Deleteing from list one removes it from my DB without any problems. When i then request the listpicker again it shows me the items in my DB, when i delete another item the rowid is incorrect.

Comment: to ask a new question, please use the [Ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button

Comment: Its allpart of the same problem you have helped with. Do you want me to ask a new question but then have to explain all this again? Im getting abit confused as to wether your trying to help me out with my problem or just be awkward! Its all realted to the main question